# Introduce a new configuration parameter in Linux Kernel make menuconfig

Tags: configuration, makefile, linux-kernel

I added a feature in Linux kernel which I switch on/off using pre-processor macros. I now want these macros to be available in `make menuconfig` as configuration parameters. I tried to add them in the default configuration file but the make process does not recognize its format (it gives error). Is there a special way to add preprocessor macros to the configuration file (for e.g. preceding the paramater name with a **CONFIG_***)?

I am not too experienced with the configuration process. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild).

Comment: @CL Thank you for the link. I will certainly go through it.

Comment: @SamratDas  Thanks for the link. This exactly what I was looking for. I still have to try the solution in the link (will do so on Monday) after which I will mark it solved (if I succeed).

Answer (score 4):

menuconfig configuration is done by 2 files that exists in almost any directory in the kernel code. Kconfig and Makefile
To add a new configuration you need to choose the directory based on the settings you want to add and edit the 2 files:
on Kconfig you need to add:

```
config MY_SETTING
    bool “This is the menuconfig label”
    default y
    help
       help for your new option
```

Edit the Makefile in the same directory and add:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_MY_SETTING)       += yournewcode.o
```

The constant CONFIG_MY_SETTING is defined by the kernel and contains 'y' if the user select it from the menuconfig 
you can also change 'bool' to 'tristate' if you want to add a file as a loadable module and the above constant contains 'm' if user choose to compile it as a module

if you don't need any file associated with the constant just declare it in Kconfig file

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But my question is a duplicate which is answered in the link shared by Jakuje.